# Faster implementation of pixel mapping

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

This method is very slow. The short and sweet is that it takes in a dictionary `phase_color_labels` that maps an arbitrary name to a 3 element list that corresponds to RGB values, and it maps each pixel of the input image to whatever pixel value that it is closest to in the `phase_color_labels` dictionary. I haven't figured out if there is a vectorized version of this that would run much faster.

The `image` variable is just a numpy array [H, W, Channels].

```
def map_pixels_to_discrete_values(image, phase_color_labels):
        """
        Takes an image with floating point pixel values and maps each pixel RGB value
        to a new value based on the closest Euclidean distance to one of the RGB sets
        in the phase_label input dictionary.
        """
        mapped_image = np.copy(image)
        for i in range(mapped_image.shape[0]):
            for j in range(mapped_image.shape[1]):
                min_distance = np.inf
                min_distance_label = None
                for phase_name, phase_color in phase_color_labels.items():
                    r = phase_color[0]
                    g = phase_color[1]
                    b = phase_color[2]
                    rgb_distance = (mapped_image[i, j, 0] - r)**2 + (mapped_image[i, j, 1] - g)**2 + (mapped_image[i, j, 2] - b)**2
                    if rgb_distance < min_distance:
                        min_distance = rgb_distance
                        min_distance_label = phase_name

                mapped_image[i, j, :] = phase_color_labels[min_distance_label]
        return mapped_image
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do things fast with Numpy, you generally want to avoid loops and push as much of the work as possible into Numpy's matrix operations.

Basic idea of my answer:

1. Get the colors from `phase_color_labels` as an `ndarray`, `phase_colors`.
2. Use Numpy's [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to compute the "outer distance"—the euclidean distance between each image in the array and each color in `phase_colors`.
3. Find the index of the color with the lowest distance for each pixel, and use those as indices in `phase_colors`.

```
phase_colors = np.array([color for color in phase_color_labels.values()])

distances = np.sqrt(np.sum((image[:,:,np.newaxis,:] - phase_colors) ** 2, axis=3))
min_indices = distances.argmin(2)

mapped_image = phase_colors[min_indices]
```

The third line warrants some additional explanation. First, note that `phase_names` and `phase_colors` both have shape `(L, C)`, where `L` is the number of labels and `C` is the number of channels.

- `image[:,:,np.newaxis,:]` inserts a new axis between the second and third axes, so the resulting array has shape `(H, W, 1, C)`.
- When subtracting an array of shape `(L, C)` from an array of shape `(H, W, 1, C)`, Numpy broadcasts the arrays to shape `(H, W, L, C)`. You can find more details on Numpy's broadcasting semantics [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).
- Then, taking the sum along axis 3 produces an array of shape `(H, W, L)`.
- (Neither squaring nor taking the square root effect the shape of the array.)

In the fourth line, using `argmin` on axis 2 then reduces the array to shape `(H, W)`, with each value being an index from the reduced axis `L`—in other words, an index into `phase_colors`.

---

As an additional improvement, because square root is a monotonically increasing function, it won't change which distance is smallest, so you can remove it entirely.

Note that with large `image` and `phase_color_labels`, the memory costs of the broadcasting may be noticeable, which may also cause performance issues.

Comment: I'm blanking out on where the broadcasting algorithm that you've provided would go into my method. In the end I'm returning a mapped_image variable which is just the copy of the original image with each pixel replaced with the closest one. How does the variable "names" apply to obtain "mapped_image"?

Comment: Those five lines should replace the entire function. `names` is `mapped_image`; I'll change that in my answer.

Comment: I believe that last line should be phase_colors not phase_names as the intended output is an RGB image. Would you agree?

Comment: Oh, yes, I misread that bit. You can discard `phase_names` entirely. I've updated my answer again.