# How to digitise and use a color scale to analyse areas of an RGB image with Numpy

Tags: python

I have a RGB picture in dicom format, extracted as a 3 dimensional numpy array with pydicom package.

The image looks like this one:

[image]

I would like to quantify the mean RGB value of one of the squares in the image, based on the color scale to the right (embedded in the image).

I have a general idea about the approach:

- build a RGB profile from the color scale and match it to the represented measure  (say from -10 to 30 in this example)
- get the average RGB value from the square of interest
- compare the average RGB value to the scale to get the measure it is closest to.

I found a few examples of color analyser scripts but nothing doing this exactly. Has anyone a suggestion or an example I could look at?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this is useful to someone, here was what I ended up doing:

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread('data/Untitled.jpg'), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)  # shape (640, 796, 3)

color_bar = img[139:477, 695:715, :]  # coordinates retrieved manually for the example
roi = img[212:301, 262:352, :]  # region of interest, a square on the figure

# average colors over the bar width to get unique rgb values over the scale length
color_profile = color_bar.mean(axis=1, dtype=int)
# array of values matching color bar (values to measure in the image)
real_values = np.linspace(30, -14, color_profile.shape[0])#.reshape(color_profile.shape[0], 1)

mean_rgb = roi.mean(axis=(0, 1), dtype=int)

# What follows was adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/55464480/13147488
# distances between mean RGB value in ROI and RGB values in color bar
distances = np.sqrt(np.sum((mean_rgb - color_profile) ** 2, axis=-1))
# indices of closest corresponding RGB value in color bar
min_index = distances.argmin()
mapped_value = real_values[min_index]
```

An alternative was also to map RGB values with corresponding "real values" and calculate their mean in the end:

```py
# distances between RGB values of each pixel in ROI and RGB values in color bar
distances = np.sqrt(np.sum((roi[:, :, np.newaxis, :] - color_profile) ** 2, axis=3))
min_indices = distances.argmin(2)

mapped_values = real_values[min_indices]
mean = mapped_values.mean(axis=(0, 1))
```